# Что такое OLTP?

Tags: база-данных, big-data, data-structures, olap

С этой технологией связано OLAP. Но здесь всё понятно -- это многомерные кубы, в которых хранятся данные. Т.е. эдакий многомерный массив, да и только.

Возможно ли представить OLTP, как можно представить OLAP-куб?

Comment: вот , что wiki говорит: OLTP-приложениями охватывается широкий спектр задач во многих отраслях — автоматизированные банковские системы, ERP-системы (системы планирования ресурсов предприятия), банковские и биржевые операции, в промышленности — регистрация прохождения детали на конвейере, фиксация в статистике посещений очередного посетителя веб-сайта, автоматизация бухгалтерского, складского учёта и учёта документов и т. п. Приложения OLTP, как правило, автоматизируют структурированные, повторяющиеся задачи обработки данных, такие как ввод заказов и банковские транзакции.

Comment: Окей. Это я и так прочитал. Но, скажем, коли я сам хочу её реализовать, то как мне начать?

Comment: определитесь сначала с назначением своей будущей системы. как правило OLAP-системы строятся на основе схемы звезда, а в OLTP редко встречается такое решение. Также в базах OLTP, как правило, хорошая нормализация данных и таблицы спроектированы для быстрой записи в транзакции в многопользовательском режиме.

Comment: Хорошо. Предположим, я работаю в банке, мне нужно заполнить информацию по клиентам.

Comment: выделите все сущности в отдельные таблицы. добавление/изменение/удаление сделайте как можно с меньшим набором данных в одной короткой транзакции

Comment: @Konst Что в моём случае под сущностями будет подразумеваться? И в чём, в итоге, фишка OLTP?

Comment: "фишка" OLTP в скорости и надёжности

Comment: @Konst почему СУБД не подходяТ?

Comment: как так СУБД не подходят, кто вам такое сказал? как раз в OLTP используют реляционные СУБД

Comment: @Konst я же это и пытаюсь понять, что из себя OLTP представляют. Т.е. OLTP можно получить из обычной СУБД? Скажем, из oracle?

Comment: да, можно на Oracle, MS SQL, DB2, MySQL и тд и тп

Comment: В таком случае, что мне нужно сделать для того, чтобы превратить СУБД в OLTP?

Comment: [OLTP (Online Transaction Processing), транзакционная система — обработка транзакций в реальном времени.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот например, продажа билетов на электричку. Каждый день, много народу делает одну и ту же операцию. Основные характеристики: фиксированные операции (билет выглядит у всех практически одинаково) и большой поток входных данных. Понятно, что если использовать традиционный (как с сайтами, например) подход СУБД без допиливаний, то это будет крайне неэффективно, т.к. бОльшая часть функционала будет вообще простаивать, а то еще и вмешиваться куда не просят. OLTP система по прежнему в своей основе имеет, а может и не иметь традиционную СУБД, но уже ориентированную на скорость. Как можно повысить скорость - заранее известные размеры запросы, перечислимое множество полей (зона, направление, конечная и т.д.), относительно простая структура самого хранилища (чтобы не пришлось выполнять трехэтажные запросы), простые механизмы контроля целостности (транзакционность). Отсюда и online - налету, transaction - все действия должны доводиться до конца, processing - процессинг :). В целом, OLTP это концепция, которая может задавать, помогать и подсказывать как лучше реализовать быструю обработку всяческих больших потоков данных. Как то так

Comment: Т.е. OLTP реализована на обычной СУБД?

Comment: может, а можете свое собственное решение предложить, хоть на базе файловой системы. Поймите, OLTP - это концепция скорее, нежели какой то конкретный продукт или технология. Да есть решения и рекомендации по реализации, но в целом Вы не ограничены в плане имплементации (но рекомендуется подсмотреть как делают если что :)) OLTP это как конвейер, будут сборкой заниматься люди, роботы это вопрос владельца фабрики.

Comment: Может посоветуете, где можно посмотреть пример реализации на базе СУБД?

Comment: База данных AdventureWorks от Микрософт:  https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms124659(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

`OLTP` - это транзакционные системы. Т.е. системы ориентированные на быстрое добавление транзакций (операций) и, возможно, их изменения. Т.е. добавить документ, изменить документ, удалить документ.

Главный приоритет `OLTP` - скорость фиксации транзакций. Отчетность и анализ в `OLTP` - это уже второй приоритет. Архитектура приложений это уже следствие специфики этой задачи. "Да" - `РСУБД` лучше подходит для `OLTP` систем. Кэши и сервера в данном случае совсем не обязательны.

В `OLAP` же наоборот - главный приоритет это быстрое получение различных аналитических выборок, с фильтрами и агрегатам. `OLAP` можно сказать это интерактивная отчетность.