# Как подготовить OLTP данные для OLAP?

Tags: база-данных, хранение-данных, olap, анализ-данных

Есть 2 способа разделения (хранения) данных: OLTP и OLAP

Прочитал про эти способы очень много статей, но не смог найти ответ на вопрос.

Рассмотрим следующую (вымышленную) ситуацию:

1. Предположим есть некий маркетплейс, на котором люди либо размещают товар для продажи, либо покупают товар.
2. Человек покупает товар, его транзакция записывается в бд, например PostgresQL (маркетплейс записывает транзакцию, так как юзер может потребовать историю своих покупок)
3. Человек, которые размещает товар, хочет проанализировать, кто покупает его товар, какая возрастная группа, процентное соотношение пола, кол-во проданного товара за прошлую неделю

Вот тут начинается то, что я не могу понять. Есть бд с транзакциями и бд с пользователями, как маркетплейс может отдать продавцу данные из третьего пункта? Для анализа обычно используют OLAP (колоночную бд, например ClickHouse), но данные-то у нас в PostgresQL.

Как совместить возможность хранить данные и возможность их анализировать?

Comment: Я задавал вопрос про OLAP и OLTP. Вряд ли по теме, но, возможно, поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458341/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-oltp

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, я уже смотрел это материал, когда искал ответ на свой вопрос. Я понимаю как работает и OLTP и OLAP, но бывают случаи, когда нужно анализировать OLTP данные, и вопрос в том как это сделать

Answer (score 2):

В разрезе БД:

**OLTP** - быстро добавлять и изменять данные.
**OLAP** - быстро читать данные. `Аналитика` - это уже [синтаксический сахар](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80),типа аггрегаций (которые доступны и в OLTP!), на основе операции чтения данных.

Разница лишь в скорости выполнения этих операций

Идеи:

- Если даннные из п2 записываются и не изменяются, то можно сразу
  класть в CH и тогда проблема отпадает.
- Также можно сделать реплику PG в CH и периодически перегонять данные (bash, ORM, drivers, etc). По структуре БД, если сравнить CH (OLAP) и PG (OLTP), то они не сильно различаются и можно из одной в другую напрямую данные перебрасывать (обращая во внимание на особенности формата, например, реализации `NULL`)
- В целом ещё могу посоветовать посмотреть в сторону: [ODBC PG Driver](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/ODBC_Driver_for_PostgreSQL) и [Внешние словари CH](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/query_language/dicts/external_dicts_dict_sources/)

**tl;dr** если нагрузки небольшие, то можно и обойтись тем же postgresql или ch для обеих задач.